# Enable Sound for RDP in Windows Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services

I am loving remote desktop in Windows Server 2012.  One problem - I can't figure out how to enable sound.  The usual remote desktop/terminal services tools are missing in 2012. (See [tsconfig.msc / tsadmin.msc in Server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/469980/tsconfig-msc-tsadmin-msc-in-server-2012) on this site)

I have changed local group policy and set "Allow audio and video playback redirection" to enabled, which did not solve my problem.  That's the only setting I can find.

This server is not part of a domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder services must be running in order for audio to work.  The second service doesn't run automatically in Windows Server 2012.  Change the service to start automatically, start it, and you're good to go.